# Auto refresh webview, when user wants to scroll over application top border

Tags: android, scrollview

I am trying to make a simple android app.

It is supposed to show a webview with some url. The trick is: I want to refresh webview, when user wants to scroll over the top application border (then a text box should appear saying that webview is being refreshed).

Something like that is implemented in Dolphin Webzine: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dolphin.browser.magazines&hl=pl

When you take i.e. Wired and then scroll over the top, feed will be updated. Any ideas how to do that? I am completely lost now.

Comment: do U mean that pull to refresh. if check this link  https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//do U mean that pull to refresh.

[click here to Download full source code](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh/zipball/master)